# Need to improve password system catagorization

Tags: java, passwords

I have this password system that relies on four character types to determine whether a password is one of four categories:

```
  boolean upper=false;
  boolean lower=false;
  boolean number=false;
  boolean symbol=false;

   for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++)
   {
     character=password.charAt(i);

     if ((character>=65)&&(character<=90)){
     System.out.println("This character is a uppercase letter:" +character);
     upper=true;}
     if ((character>=97)&&(character<=122)){
     System.out.println("This character is a lowercase letter:" +character);
     lower=true;}
     if ((character>=48)&&(character<=57)){
     System.out.println("This character is a number:" +character);
     number=true;}
     if (((character>=33)&&(character<=47))||((character>=58)&&(character<=64))||((character>=93)&&(character<=96))||((character>=123)&&(character<=126))){
     System.out.println("This character is a symbol:" +character);
     symbol=true;}
   }
```

This is how I put them into four categories: WEAK, MEDIUM, STRONG, and SUPERSTRONG:

```
   boolean weak=false;
   boolean medium=false;
   boolean strong=false;
   boolean superstrong=false;


       int level = 0;

   if((upper=true) || (lower=true) || (number=true) || (symbol=true)) {
        weak=true;
            level++;}

     if (((upper=true) && (lower=true)) || ((upper=true) && (number=true)) || ((upper=true) && (symbol=true)) || ((lower=true) && (symbol=true)) || ((lower=true) && (number=true)) || ((number=true) && (symbol=true))){
         medium=true;
            level++;}

     if(((upper=true) && (lower=true) && (number=true)) || ((upper=true) && (lower=true) && (symbol=true)) || ((upper=true) && (number=true) && (symbol=true)) || ((lower=true) && (number=true) && (symbol=true))){
         strong=true;
             level++;}

     if((upper=true) && (lower=true) && (number=true) && (symbol=true)){
         superstrong=true;
            level++;}

     if(level >= 1){
         System.out.println("This password is weak ");}
     if(level >= 2){
         System.out.println("This password is medium.");}
     if(level >= 3){
         System.out.println("This password is strong.");}
     if(level >= 4){
         System.out.println("This password is super strong.");}
     }
```

The problem is that it compiles without error, and the password checker checks the password to the right category, but the problem is that no matter how many types of characters there are in the password, the category will always be outputted as SUPERSTRONG. I have tried this on all lowercase passwords and all other types of password possible in this system but this always happens.
How may I solve this problem?

Here's the code in its entirety if it helps:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class passwordChecker
{

public static void main(String [] args) 
{
boolean repeat=true;
String password;
int length;

while(repeat==true){

System.out.println ("Please enter your password.");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
password=scan.nextLine();
length=password.length();

if(length<=6 | length>=12) {
System.out.println("Your password does not meet the requirements. 
Please enter a new password.");
} 
else {
System.out.println("Your password meets the criteria.");
 char character='\0';
  boolean upper=false;
  boolean lower=false;
  boolean number=false;
  boolean symbol=false;

   for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++)
   {
     character=password.charAt(i);

     if ((character>=65)&&(character<=90)){
     System.out.println("This character is a uppercase letter:"                    +character);
     upper=true;}
     if ((character>=97)&&(character<=122)){
     System.out.println("This character is a lowercase letter:" +character);
     lower=true;}
     if ((character>=48)&&(character<=57)){
     System.out.println("This character is a number:" +character);
     number=true;}
     if (((character>=33)&&(character<=47))||((character>=58)&&`enter code here`(character<=64))||((character>=93)&&(character<=96))||`enter code here`((character>=123)&&(character<=126))){
     System.out.println("This character is a symbol:" +character);
     symbol=true;}
   }
   boolean weak=false;
   boolean medium=false;
   boolean strong=false;
   boolean superstrong=false;


       int level = 0;

   if((upper=true) || (lower=true) || (number=true) || (symbol=true)) {
        weak=true;
            level++;}

     if (((upper=true) && (lower=true)) || ((upper=true) && (number=true)) || ((upper=true) && (symbol=true)) || ((lower=true) && (symbol=true)) || ((lower=true) && (number=true)) || ((number=true) && `enter code here`(symbol=true))){
         medium=true;
            level++;}

     if(((upper=true) && (lower=true) && (number=true)) || ((upper=true) && (lower=true) && (symbol=true)) || ((upper=true) && (number=true) && (symbol=true)) || ((lower=true) && (number=true) && (symbol=true))){
         strong=true;
             level++;}

     if((upper=true) && (lower=true) && (number=true) && (symbol=true)){
         superstrong=true;
            level++;}

     if(level >= 1){
         System.out.println("This password is weak ");}
     if(level >= 2){
         System.out.println("This password is medium.");}
     if(level >= 3){
         System.out.println("This password is strong.");}
     if(level >= 4){
         System.out.println("This password is super strong.");}
     }



 System.out.println("Do you want to enter another password?");
 Scanner scan2 = new Scanner (System.in);
 String choice=scan2.nextLine();
 if(choice.equals("yes")||choice.equals("Yes")) repeat = true;
 else{
 repeat=false;
 }}}}
```

Sorry if the code looks like it shouldnt. It should just work all fine if you type it in as normal.

Comment: This `if(.. upper=true ...)` first assigns `true` to `upper` then tests value of `upper` (which will be obviously true now). If you want to compare use `==` operator (or don't use `==` at all, simple `if (boolValue)` is same as `if (boolValue==true)` and will stop you from making this kind of mistake, for negation simply use `if (!boolValue)`).

Comment: There is too much wrong with this approach to make it worth "fixing" without completely rewriting it.  The most instructive thing you can do is to step through it in you IDE debugger to see exactly what it does, which I guarantee will provide you with several surprises.  Code does not behave the way you seem to believe it does, and you must step through it to learn what is actually happening.  Also, the idea of classifying password strength based on whether it contains certain character classes is itself a weak test.  You need to research basic information theory and learn about "entropy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
upper=true
```

you are assigning `upper` to be `true`.

So when you do

```
if (upper=true)
```

this is the same as

```
upper=true;
if (upper)
```

I suspect you wanted to use `==` for comparison however a better solution is to use the boolean as a condition.

```
if (upper || lower || number || symbol) {
```

BTW a better way to check for characters is

```
if (Character.isUppercase(ch)) {
   // upper case
} else if (Character.isLowercase(ch)) {
   // is lower
} else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
   // is digit
} else {
   // is symbol
}
```

and for levels you can do

```
int level = (upper?1:0) + (lower?1:0) + (number?1:0) + (symbol?1:0);
```